# Разобрать слово по составу

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Подскажите пожалуйста от какого слова было образовано слово ***усыновить*** и как разобрать его по составу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Тихонова: сын - у/сын/ови/ть.

Суффикс ОВИ  - сложный суффикс ОВ+И,  ОВ относится к форме мн. числа "сыновья".